# How input and output multiplexers work in ADV7800?

Tags: integrated-circuit, analog, decoder

I was going through IC ADV7800 datasheet, getting confused with the functionality of two multiplexers given in its block diagram. Attaching picture of the same.
[image]

For first MUX there is 12 inputs and 4 outputs, and for second one there is 4 input and four output. How it is possible ?

Edit:
Detailed block diagram

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't get hung up on block diagrams using exact terminology or internal symbols that somehow translate to a logic chip. Read the first multiplexer as having the ability to route any of the signals to any of the outputs. In practice not all options will be implemented because there's no point having a scart signal and (say) green (from RGB) being digitized simultaneously.

For the 2nd multiplexer read it as some form of cross-point switch - there are 4 inputs and 4 outputs - the real internal logic decides the order in which those 4 inputs are routed to the four outputs.

Comment: Even in this datasheet details about the MUX is missing. Where should I refer to get complete details?

Comment: If the data sheet lacks information you need, contact the supplier.